# Resharper API development - Find Incoming calls

Tags: api, resharper, resharper-5.0

I am trying to make a program which will utilize resharper's "find incoming calls" feature. This is not a resharper plugin, but rather a console app (or similar) which finds the incoming calls to all properties on several particular types in my code.

I have been searching the web for quite some time to find this, and have come up with nothing. The documentation for the resharper API is lacking to say the least!

Looking at the dlls in Reflector doesn't seem to help much either, as all of the classes and methods I could find seem to require variables whose types are all internal...

Of course, if there is another way to get this information, in a way similar to how resharper does it (visual studio's "Call Hierarchy" isn't quite as good, it doesn't find things from the base interface etc), I would be more than happy to hear it! In which case, you would need to know that I am using C#.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ReSharper API is working only under Visual Studio. It will not work in console application.

Comment: Thanks! That is unfortunate, but understandable I guess. I was kinda hoping to be able to pass it an arbitrary sln file and then work with the public methods to get my results. Ah well.

Comment: It's in plans, standalone core. In future versions.